# How do I install libSBML using Cygwin on a Windows machine?

Tags: cygwin, sbml

I want to install libSBML using a Cygwin terminal on my Windows machine in order to run a bespoke statistical package in Python. The libSBML installation instructions have enabled me to successfully execute the following:

```
./configure --with-python=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64 --prefix=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64 --with-swig=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64

make
```

however,

```
make install
```

fails giving the following error:

```
/bindings/python/RyY1P1Dc/stage//usr/local/lib/_libsbml.a
ranlib /cygdrive/c/Users/esrnai/Downloads/libsbml-4.0.1-src/libsbml-     4.0.1/src/bindings/python/RyY1P1Dc/stage//usr/local/lib/_libsbml.a
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/local/lib'
mkdir -p build build/libsbml
echo "libsbml" > build/libsbml.pth
cp _libsbml.dll  build/libsbml
cp: cannot stat ‘_libsbml.dll’: No such file or directory
Makefile:316: recipe for target 'create-build-dir' failed
make[3]: *** [create-build-dir] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/esrnai/Downloads/libsbml-  4.0.1-src/libsbml-4.0.1/src/bindings/python'
../../config/makefile-common-actions.mk:359: recipe for target 'python-  recurse' failed
make[2]: *** [python-recurse] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/esrnai/Downloads/libsbml-   4.0.1-src/libsbml-4.0.1/src/bindings'
../config/makefile-common-actions.mk:359: recipe for target 'bindings-   recurse' failed
make[1]: *** [bindings-recurse] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/esrnai/Downloads/libsbml-  4.0.1-src/libsbml-4.0.1/src'
config/makefile-common-actions.mk:361: recipe for target 'src-recurse'   failed
make: *** [src-recurse] Error 2
```

I believe the problem is the same as the one reported here http://sourceforge.net/p/sbml/libsbml/314/#581b which has since been closed. Could someone help me interpret the message on this page or suggest any alternative solutions?

Comment: According to the bug report, you need `file` to build a shared library.  Do you have `file` installed on your system?

Comment: I'm not sure. What's the best way to check if `file` is installed?

Comment: `which file` or `cygcheck -c file`

Comment: Yes, it appears `file` is definitely installed on the system

Comment: The other question is why are you trying to build such an old version?  The current stable release is 5.11.4, you're using 4.0.1, which is even older than the bug report you referenced.

Comment: I have downloaded the 5.11.4 release and the `make install` still gives the identical error.

Answer (score 0):

I have now overcome this problem through the following solution:

I downloaded libSBML as a standalone python package from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-libsbml/python-libsbml-5.11.4.tar.gz

I then entered the appropriate directory and typed the following commands:

```
tar xzf python-libsbml-5.11.4.tar.gz
cd python-libsbml-5.11.4
python setup.py install
```

and libSBML was successfully installed. I am now able to run the statistical package without failure.